# mod_proxy balancer member status "disabled" vs "stopped"

Tags: apache, mod-proxy

I'm using Apache 2.2 with mod_proxy and I'm trying to do some traffic control.
The balancer manager allows me to change the status:

> D: Worker is disabled and will not accept any requests.
>
> S: Worker is administratively stopped.
>
> I: Worker is in ignore-errors mode and will always be considered available.
>
> H: Worker is in hot-standby mode and will only be used if no other viable workers are available.
>
> E: Worker is in an error state.
>
> N: Worker is in drain mode and will only accept existing sticky sessions destined for itself and ignore all other requests.

but from the documentation, I cannot figure out how "D" (disabled) is different from "S".

My guess is, "S" will not return requests that are still processing while "D" will.
For my purpose, I only want to stop new requests and allow existing requests to finish. Will "D" do that?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation here:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html

D: Worker is disabled and will not accept any requests; will be automatically retried.

S: Worker is administratively stopped; will not accept requests and will not be automatically retried

The difference between the two: in D state, the worker will be automatically retried, whereas in S state, the worker will not be automatically retried. Both will not accept requests.

If you only want to stop new requests, but let existing ones to finish, I think you would want to use N (drain mode). You are wanting to "drain" the worker of requests until there are none left for it to handle.

Hope this helps.

Comment: but isn't "drain" mode related to sticky sessions? I don't have sticky sessions.
From the documentation, it seems "drain" mode still accepts new requests, if they have the sticky session cookie.

Comment: So you only have 1 balancer member?

Comment: no, 2 load balancers and 2 members. We're stateless so we don't need sticky sessions.